# Lore installation pip error

Tags: python, pip

The line "pip install lore" generates an exception. 
I tried using pip2 and pip3 but none seem to be working.

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cBrW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package is most likely broken, and if you look at one of the more recent changes they added an invalid line [here](https://github.com/instacart/lore/commit/c371f94c5e2e912834c3efe3152c73369bbadc23#diff-2eeaed663bd0d25b7e608891384b7298R62) in the setup file.

```
     install_requires=[
+        'flask>=0.12.2, <0.12.99'
         'future>=0.15, <0.16.99',
```

See the missing comma ^.

This causes the two lines to get concatenated into

> flask>=0.12.2, <0.12.99future>=0.15, <0.16.99

**Update**

I reported the issue to the library author [here](https://github.com/instacart/lore/issues/82) and they fixed it.